# AS3 XMLListCollection data sorting on multiple fields and crashing when value changed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

My XML:

```
<destinations>
    <destination>
        <fav>1</fav>
        <cheapest>140</cheapest>
    </destination>
    <destination>
        <fav>0</fav>
        <cheapest>150</cheapest>
    </destination>
</destinations>
```

I am creating XMLListCollection for my spark List component.

```
var dataprovider:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xml.destination);
```

I am trying to sort this XMLListCollection using fav and cheapest element.

```
var sort:Sort = new Sort();
sort.fields = [new SortField("fav" , true , true)];
sort.fields.push(new SortField("cheapest" , false , true));
dataprovider.sort = sort;
dataprovider.refresh();
```

Everything works fine till I update value of fav:

```
xml.destination.(id == String(destId))[0].fav = 0;
```

XML structure looks exactly the same after the update but I get thrown error from my itemrenderer object :

```
override public function set data( value:Object ) : void { 
    dest_name.text = value.text;
}
```

Error stating that value is null. How can value be null in the first place? I get no error when I remove fav from sort fields or update cheapest element instead.

Does anyone have any idea about this anomaly?

Comment: Where is dest_name coming from?  I don't see it in your xml. Could the object represented by dest_name be a temporary var? (i.e. declared inside a function that has finished executing?)

Comment: Another possibility is that "id == String(destId)" is not returning any matches.

Comment: The XML data is updating nicely. dest_name is label element. The thing missing, as I stated in my post, is param named "value", which is given to the function automatically by flex framework from dataprovider.

Comment: Double check that "xml.destination.(id == String(destId))[0]"  is returning a valid match.

Comment: It does, I forgot to mention that the example is heavily ripped of code for make it easier and faster to read. Id tag also exists in xml code.

Comment: The issue is connected to multiple field sort and changing the value of dataprovider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account that your itemrenderers are recycled, for example, if order of items in your collection changes(when you change value of sort field). When renderers are recycled, null can be passed to set data function.

That means your function

```
override public function set data( value:Object ) : void { 
    dest_name.text = value.text;
}
```

shall be changed like that:

```
override public function set data( value:Object ) : void { 
    if(value){
         dest_name.text = value.text;
    }
}
```

You should always keep this in mind when implementing item renderers.

Comment: Yes I already figured it out myself but didn't update this post yet. But thanks for the effort.